# [windbg]kd - sxe ld <dll> from a process context won't fire

Tags: windows, windbg, kernel-mode

I'm trying to stop at a specific module load from a kernel debugger inside a specific process context.

What i do is to first set `sxe ld [process-name]` let's say calc.exe.

Now, when I run calc it works, but when i set `sxe ld [dll-name]` (say kernel32/ntdll) it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think usually this enables stopping on loading of kernel modules only (e.g. drivers). However, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319716/how-do-i-debug-a-process-that-starts-at-boot-time) claims it can work for user-mode processes if you send `!gflag +ksl` first (Enable loading of kernel debugger symbols).

It also describes how you can set process-specific kernel  breakpoints, e.g.

```
kd> .process
    Implicit process is now 00112233`44556677
bp /p 0011223344556677 nt!NtMapViewOfSection
```

The `NtMapViewOfSection` syscall is used, among other purposes, to load DLLs so by stopping at it you should catch all further DLL loads.